# Tumblr API - Retrieved post not displaying media

Tags: javascript, tumblr

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am a long time reader, first time poster. Have gotten tons of help from really smart people on this site through other's questions, but I've encountered a problem that has actually compelled me to sign up. Hopefully this post helps somebody else out who's looking for this same information.

I've been trying to figure out the easiest way to display blog information on one of my sites.

I decided to use tumblr and it's API to display this information. This is the code I've come across thats gotten me pretty far along the way:

html

```
  <div id="Posts"><ul></ul></div>
```

javascript

```
function loadPosts () {

var key = "api_key=1waQ1OkbKW817GisHWCO0sIRZC4IP7sXeCK7EFulQskOYonz5E";
var api = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/cantbrooklyn.tumblr.com/";
var retrieve_more = function (offset) {
    $.getJSON(api + "posts?callback=?&limit=20&offset=" + offset + "&" + key,function(data) {
        $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {
            var content = item.body;
            $("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + content + '</li>')
        });

        if (data.response.posts.length == 20) {
            retrieve_more(offset + 20);
        }
    });
};

retrieve_more(0);
}

loadPosts();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cantbk/mmwg5a5c/#&togetherjs=EI7Qyj48rL)

If you check the results of the code in jsfiddle, you will see a long list of my posts, but with many instances of the word "undefined." Each "undefined" is supposed to be one of my media post, showing a photo or a video. What's confusing is that images in my textual posts are showing up fine. So somewhere in the javascript, my code is omitting everything but text posts. If anybody has any idea what's wrong, I would appreciate the advice.

Thanks in advance!

zach

Comment: I have made a start here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/qy9p4crm/2/ the issue you have is that `content` or `item.body` returns undefined for video and audio posts (and possibly others). So you have to output the post type then wrap everything in if/else conditions to iterate through the different post types and output the content differently. There are other questions on SO that cover this, and I might have some code somewhere if I can dig it out.

Comment: Hey thanks, looks great. Now I just have to get it to display the content. I'm going to take a closer look and do some internet reading on it. Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: I have found a version of the script, but it uses a switch statement and it's incredibly verbose. Lots of room for improvement. There is a paired down version here: http://ios.phonesdevelopers.com/73_19043857/